# stochastic integral convergence in probability (updated)

Tags: stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

My goal is to prove that for all $t\geq 0$
\begin{equation}
\frac{\int_{t}^{t+h} H_s dB_s} {B_{t+h}-B_{t}} \rightarrow H_t
\end{equation}
in probability, where $B$ is a Brownian motion and $H$ continuous and bounded.

Almost the same question was asked here: ["Continuity" of stochastic integral wrt Brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573000/continuity-of-stochastic-integral-wrt-brownian-motion)

When I follow the steps in the above thread, I get

\begin{equation}
P \left( \left| \frac{\int_{t}^{t+h} H_s dB_s} {B_{t+h}-B_{t}} - H_t  \right| > \epsilon \right) \leq P\left( \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{h}} \int_{t}^{t+h} (H_s-H_t) dB_s  \right| > \epsilon/K \right) + \frac{\epsilon}{4}
\end{equation}
Now in the above thread it is said that one should use the Markov-inequality and then the Ito-isometry. But I don't get how I can use the Ito isometry after I apply the Markov-inequality. Markov would give me that the probability on the right hand side is less or equal to:
\begin{equation}
E\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{h}} \left| \int_{t}^{t+h} (H_s-H_t) dB_s  \right| \right) \, \frac{K}{\epsilon} \ . 
\end{equation}
Any ideas on how to show that the above 
converges to $0$ as $h\to 0$ (using the Ito isometry)?

**Edit**: The rest of the proof:
Using Chebychev's inequality we have (ignoring constants)
\begin{equation}
E \left( \frac{1}{h} \left( \int_t^{t+h} (H_s -H_t) dB_s \right)^2 \right) = \frac{1}{h} \int_t^{t+h} E(H_s -H_t)^2 ds \to 0
\end{equation} 
as $h \to 0$ by the Ito isometry.

Comment: $H$ is random or not?

Comment: Yes, $H$ is a stochastic process that is continuous and bounded.

Comment: Since you want to invoke Ito isometry, you may want to use Chebychev's inequality. Note that in some literature, Markov's inequality refers to the concentration inequality of the form $$\mathbb{P}(|X| \geq x) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[\varphi(|X|)]}{\varphi(x)} $$ for $x > 0$ and an increasing function $\varphi : [0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$. Then the Markov's inequality in the narrow sense and the Chebyshev's inequality correspond to $\varphi(x) = x$ and $\varphi(x) = x^2$, respectively.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you, that actually did the trick. I will edit my answer above and provide a proof.

Comment: Glad it helped :)